# REGEXP_REPLACE issue in LookerStudio

Tags: regex, looker-studio

Currently, I am facing an issue where I am using a number as text in LookerStudio and would like to add a thousand separators to it while keeping it as text.

The value that I am using is 12345678 and I would like it to be 12,345,678

I tried using the following `REGEXP_REPLACE` function:

```sql
CONCAT("Value = ", REGEXP_REPLACE(CAST(my_value AS TEXT),"\\B(?=(\\d{3})+(?!\\d))", ","))
```

This resulted in a broken field. Upon further investigation, referring to https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax, the ?= and ?! sections aren't supported. Can somebody perhaps assist with a workaround or a new way of doing this?

Comment: You can work around it by nesting as many `REGEXP_REPLACE(..., ",*(\\d{3})\\b,*", ",$1")` calls as needed and then `TRIM` the commas on left and right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use lookarounds in a RE2 pattern.

However, a workaround is possible if you know there can be a max amount of digit groupings (there are usually not more than four here - up to billions), and nest the `REGEXP_REPLACE` functions like

```sql
REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(col, ",*(\\d{3})\\b,*", ",$1"), ",*(\\d{3})\\b,*", ",$1"), ",*(\\d{3})\\b,*", ",$1"), ",*(\\d{3})\\b,*", ",$1")
```

Then, trim the commas at the start/end of the string.

The pattern matches

- `,*` - zero or more commas
- `(\d{3})` - Group 1: three digits
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `,*` - zero or more commas.

The `,$1` replacement replaces the matches with a comma and Group 1 value.